# Prove: $\{a_n\}>0, {\lim_{n \to \infty}} \{ a_n \}=L \Rightarrow { \lim_{n \to \infty } \{a_n \}^\frac{1}{n}}=1 $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, infinitesimals

I have this exercise to prove in calculus 1:

$$ \text{Prove:} \, \{a_n\}>0, \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}} \{ a_n \}=L \Rightarrow \displaystyle{ \lim_{n \to \infty } \{a_n \}^\frac{1}{n}}=1 $$

Where "$\{a_n\}$" is a sequence.

We proved in class that $ \displaystyle{\lim_{{n \to \infty }} \cfrac{1}{n}} = 0 $.

Any $L^0=1$.

$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}} \{ a_n \}=L,L^0=1, \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}  \frac{1}{n} = 0 \Rightarrow \\ \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}} \{ a_n  \} ^\frac{1}{n} = L^0=1 \\ QED$

Is my solution wrong? The solution of the university is different.
Their solution is:

$\text{Because} \, a_n \to L \, \text{then for} \, \epsilon = \frac{L}{2} \, \text{exists} \, N \, \text{such that} \, \forall n>N: \\ \cfrac{L}{2} = L-\cfrac{L}{2}<a_n<L+\cfrac{L}{2}=\cfrac{3L}{2} \\ \text{and therefore:} \\ 1 \leftarrow \sqrt[n]{\cfrac{L}{2}}<\sqrt[n]{a_n}<\sqrt[n]{\cfrac{3L}{2}}\to 1$

Comment: You may have missed some assumption. For example $L>0$. Note that, in general, $L$ may be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is slightly wrong. To put it in the right way, state it as $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\frac{1}{n}\log(a_n)} = e^{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\log\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n\right)} = e^{0\cdot L} = e^0 = 1$$ Since $\exp$ and $\log$ are continuous functions. However, the solution of the university uses much less additional knowledge and is therefore better. To point out the problem in your solution: You would have to proove first that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^{1/n} = \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \right)^{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}}$$ holds.

Comment: How are the first and 2nd limits you wrote with the logs equal? I don't remember logarithm rules very well. Also, would you mind stating where I was wrong, instead? It'd let me learn better.

Comment: @GalGrünfeld $\log$ is the inverse function of $\exp$, so $\exp(\log(a)) = a$ for any $a > 0$. Further it holds that $\log(a^b) = b\log(a)$. Just edited.

Comment: But we were told in class that calculating limits, when moving from limit to the value of it, all the theorems are used in a single transition. Isn't that what I did here? In a single transition I replaced the set and the expanded with what they approach to.

Comment: @GalGrünfeld As far as I understand you speak of the arithmetic laws. I am sure you've prooved in class that this holds for sums, products and quotients (under appropriate conditions) but I doubt, that you have prooven this "transitions" as you call them for powers. So you have to show this if you want to use it.

Comment: We proved arithmetical of limits. But this doesn't require any arithmetical of limits.

Comment: @GalGrünfeld Also for powers? Then your proof is fine.

Comment: I edited my answer. Why do I need to show this arithmetic of limits? The limit is for n, no matter where it is. The calculation is done in 1 transition. 1 approach of n to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Unless we add an extra assumption that $L>0$, otherwise, it is false that $\lim_n(a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$.

An obvious counter-example: Let $a_{n}=e^{-n}$. Then $a_{n}>0$ and
$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}=0$. However $(a_{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}=e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument does not work.

For example,  $ 1+1/n \to 1$ and $1^n \to 1$ but $(1+1/n)^n \to e \ne 1$